# how to fix application terminate after opening google map with directions from my custom android app

Tags: android, google-maps

After i open google map activity with direction from my custom fragment it tend to terminate the whole app.

mapView.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+currlat+","+currLon+"&daddr="+destinationLat+","+destinationLon+"&travelmode=driving")));

in here mapView means my custome fragmnet.

Comment: What is the error that is causing your app to terminate, after you open Google Maps app from your application? Can you post the error logs ?

Comment: Post the log....

Comment: V/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{bf72a32 token=android.os.BinderProxy@bc46383 {com.vega.chargenet/com.vega.chargenet.ui.activity.MainActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow@5c5864d
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =ViewRoot{ca1d5a9 com.vega.chargenet/com.vega.chargenet.ui.activity.MainActivity,ident = 1}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{adfb4df I.E...... R......D 0,0-720,1280}
D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@bc46383
Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + lastLocation.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" +
                                        destinationLocationLatitude + "," +
                                        destinationLocationLongitude));
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this one also terminate the app

Comment: @JaninduPraneethWeerawarnakul the error logs that you've posted for the question aren't clear enough to understand the issue. If the last location of the user is available and your app has the destination location details, it will launch it with Google Maps app and display the route between those two locations.

Answer (score 0):

There is this example from the [google developer doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) where you use a geo: URI instead of an url

This URI works like this :

> Use the `geo:` intent to display a map at a specified location and zoom level.

```
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
```

Here is a code that uses it. Also, it ensures that Google Maps will receive it and not another app, and if Maps isn't installed, it just does nothing but you can add an `else` statement to tell the user that he needs Maps to execute the action

```java
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

To launch navigation, use `google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude`. The starting position will be the user current location. See [this part](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) of the google developer site

```java
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: this code only give me a specific location. not a navigation

Comment: Edited my answer to add the navigation part

Comment: it also give me the same eroor

Comment: Then the error does not come from google Maps because this code works and doesn't crash my app